# Questions about Mathematical Logics

Tags: logic

I have a questions about Mathematical Logics.

(1) if x is not free in A, formula ∀x(A->B)->A->∀xB is valid.

(2) ∀x(A->B)->A->∀xB is not valid.

I don't know why these two questions have different answer when they have condition "if x is not free in A"
can anybody prove or explain these questions?
I really need your help.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to see why  the formula $∀x(A \to B)\to A \to ∀xB$ is not valid in general but it is valid in the special case where "$x$ is not free in $A$". Is this your question?

Comment: yes, that's my questions